# Hide active project in eclipse IDE

Tags: eclipse

Is there a way to hide an active project (i.e. a dynamic web project) from eclipse IDE (I'm using Luna EE)? I don't mean deleting or closing it, but just hiding it for a period of time and be able to show it again.

Comment: Did my answer solve your issue or there are still issues about this?

Comment: @toubou:  Forgive me. I would like to believe it as solution however I was not able to test it yet. I am pulled away for other priorities. As soon as I get a chance to test it I will reply back to your answer. Have a blessed day!

Answer (score 2):

You could create [working sets](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.user%2Fconcepts%2Fcworkset.htm) and divide your projects accordingly, which means that you can hide them on demand.